# Download https image with Indy for Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I've seen quite a few posts on how to download an http image to a memory stream, but I'm having trouble grabbing an https image.

I hoped it would be as easy as dropping an SSL handler in but I keep getting the following error:

> Error connecting with SSL. error:14094410:SSL reourtines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure.

The example site I've been using I think uses SSLv3.

https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1702/NGC1316_MazlinKellerMenaker1024d.jpg

Annoyingly the JSON actually returns an http node, but it gets redirected to the https version

https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY

```json
{
  "copyright": "Steve Mazlin",
  "date": "2017-02-02",
  "explanation": "An example of violence on a cosmic scale, enormous elliptical galaxy NGC 1316 lies about 75 million light-years away toward Fornax, the southern constellation of the Furnace. Investigating the startling sight, astronomers suspect the giant galaxy of colliding with smaller neighbor NGC 1317 seen just above, causing far flung loops and shells of stars. Light from their close encounter would have reached Earth some 100 million years ago. In the deep, sharp image, the central regions of NGC 1316 and NGC 1317 appear separated by over 100,000 light-years. Complex dust lanes visible within also indicate that NGC 1316 is itself the result of a merger of galaxies in the distant past. Found on the outskirts of the Fornax galaxy cluster, NGC 1316 is known as Fornax A. One of the visually brightest of the Fornax cluster galaxies it is one of the strongest and largest radio sources with radio emission extending well beyond this telescopic field-of-view, over several degrees on the sky.  Participate: Take an Aesthetics & Astronomy Survey",
  "hdurl": "http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1702/NGC1316_MazlinKellerMenaker.jpg",
  "media_type": "image",
  "service_version": "v1",
  "title": "NGC 1316: After Galaxies Collide",
  "url": "http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1702/NGC1316_MazlinKellerMenaker1024d.jpg"
}
```

Any ideas?

Side note: I have tried changing the SSL version to both `sslvTLSv1_1` and `sslvTLSv1_2` but no luck.

```
function TUrlImageReader.ReadImage: TMemoryStream;
var
  ImgMS: TMemoryStream;
  ImgHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  SSLHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  ImgMS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  SSLHandler:=TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  ImgHTTP:=TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  ImgHTTP.IOHandler:=SSLHandler;
  SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Method:=sslvSSLv3;
  try
    try
      ImgHTTP.Get(FURL, ImgMS);
    except
      on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
        ImgMS.Clear;
    end;
  finally
    ImgHTTP.Free;
    SSLHandler.Free;
  end;
  ImgMS.Position := 0;
  Result := ImgMS;
end;
```

Comment: Ah forgot to add in the error image. 
Anyway it says 
Error connecting with SSL.
error:14094410:SSL reourtines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure.

Comment: The server  apod.nasa.gov (129.164.179.22) [supports](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=apod.nasa.gov&s=129.164.179.22&latest) only TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2, not TLS 1.0 or SSLv2/v3. So if you assign SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Method:=sslvSSLv3, Indy tries to connect with only SSLv3, which will be refused by the server.

Comment: Thanks Ken. I have updated the question with the fact that I have also tried sslvTLSv1_1 and sslvTLSv1_2 but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using an up-to-date version of Indy 10 with all the latest fixes for handling TLS 1.2.  Using the current version, the code you have shown works fine for me when I set the `SSLOptions.Method` to either `sslvTLSv1_1` or `sslvTLSv1_2` (as well as when I set the `SSLOptions.SSLVersions` to `[sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2]`).  The image downloads correctly.

However, do note that there is a memory leak in your code.  If any exception *other than* `IdHTTPProtocolException` is raised, you are not freeing the `TMemoryStream` object.  Your code should look more like this instead:

```
function TUrlImageReader.ReadImage: TMemoryStream;
var
  ImgHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  SSLHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  Result := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    ImgHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    try
      SSLHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(ImgHTTP);
      SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_1; // or sslvTLSv1_2
      // or:
      // SSLHandler.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
      ImgHTTP.IOHandler := SSLHandler;
      try
        ImgHTTP.Get('https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1702/NGC1316_MazlinKellerMenaker1024d.jpg', Result);
      except
        on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
          Result.Clear;
      end;
    finally
      ImgHTTP.Free;
    end;
    Result.Position := 0;
  except
    Result.Free;
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

Also, technically you don't need to `Clear` the stream in response to `EIdHTTPProtocolException`, because nothing will have been written to it, any response data will be silently discarded by `TIdHTTP` since you are not enabling the `hoNoProtocolErrorException` and `hoWantProtocolErrorContent` flags in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property.

To avoid having to catch `EIdHTTPProtocolException` at all, you can enable the `hoNoProtocolErrorException` flag by itself, eg:

```
function TUrlImageReader.ReadImage: TMemoryStream;
var
  ImgHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  SSLHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  Result := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    ImgHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    try
      SSLHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(ImgHTTP);
      SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_1; // or sslvTLSv1_2
      // or:
      // SSLHandler.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
      ImgHTTP.IOHandler := SSLHandler;
      ImgHTTP.HTTPOptions := ImgHTTP.HTTPOptions + [hoNoProtocolErrorException];

      ImgHTTP.Get('https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1702/NGC1316_MazlinKellerMenaker1024d.jpg', Result);
    finally
      ImgHTTP.Free;
    end;
    Result.Position := 0;
  except
    Result.Free;
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Hi Remy and thanks. I should be on the latest Indy as I'm using Delphi Berlin. Maybe my OpenSSL libraries are out of date so I'll go check them. On another note, I didn't want to send back a nil object through my interface back to the calling code, would rather the stream be empty, though I might change the function to have the stream as an out property and return a boolean result.

Comment: I'll have to keep playing around as I'm still getting the same error as before. If I try your second option and use the SSLVersions line I get a slightly different error "140740BF:SSL routines:SSL23_CLIENT_HELLO:no protocols available"

Comment: Tried a Google https image and same result, so think I can rule out NASA :-)

Comment: I've updated Indy anyway to the latest version and also got the latest version from OpenSSL, still no luck.

Comment: @mikelittlewood I don't know what to tell you then. The code above works fine for me to download the URL you provided.

Comment: Not sure either Remy, I'll just have to keep playing around. Tried to run the standalone app from another PC with the same results. Never mind, but thanks for trying.

Comment: One thing I am surprised about is that all the error messages return SSL3 errors rather than TLS. Also without setting SSLHandler.SSLOptions.SSLVersions they all return handshake failure, whereas using SSLHandler.SSLOptions.SSLVersions it returns no protocols available.

Comment: @mikelittlewood OpenSSL implements its TLS 1.x logic using SSL3 functions, since TLS 1.0 is essentially SSL 3.1. So anywhere you see SSL3 in error messages, it may refer to either SSL 3.0 or TLS 1.x. On the Indy side, setting `SSLOptions.Method` updates `SSLOptions.SSLVersions` and vice versa. If you don't set either, TLS 1.0 is the default, which does not work on this particular server, only TLS 1.1 and 1.2 work.